# WCF session timeout after 20 minutes even if I'm using the application [ASP.NET]

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

My application keeps getting timed out after 20 minutes even if I'm using it.
Here's the code:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" timeout="20" />
```

Now, I know one way to fix it is increase the timeout value.But my requirement is that the application should never expire when someone is using it.
Is there any appropriate alternate solution to do so? Setting the timeout value to a really long value seems a bit drastic. Configuring IIS is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your  model is **"Custom"**. It stores session-state data using a custom session-state storage provider. Such as:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="OdbcSessionServices" 
      connectionString="DSN=SessionState;" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <sessionState 
      mode="Custom"
      customProvider="OdbcSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="OdbcSessionProvider"
          type="Samples.AspNet.Session.OdbcSessionStateStore"
          connectionStringName="OdbcSessionServices" 
          writeExceptionsToEventLog="false" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Similarly, I recommend using the other two modes, which are relatively better at storing sessions.

State server mode, where session state is stored in a separate process called the ASP.NET State service. This ensures that session state is preserved when the Web application is restarted and that session state is available to multiple Web servers in the Web farm. For example, stored on a machine called "Test1".

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="StateServer"
      stateConnectionString="tcpip=Test1:42424"
      cookieless="false"
      timeout="20"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

SQLServer mode stores session state in a SQL Server database. This ensures that session state is preserved when the Web application is restarted and that session state is available to multiple Web servers in the Web farm. Such as

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="SQLServer"
      sqlConnectionString="Integrated Security=SSPI;data 
        source=SampleSqlServer;" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi, I cannot change the mode since my entire application is configured based on it. Is there any other fix?

Comment: Hi, I think these two examples can help you [How to: Sample Session-State Store Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178589(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)[SessionStateStoreProviderBase Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatestoreproviderbase?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8.1)

Comment: It's actually stored on the server's hard drive, which allows for more durable storage.

Comment: Hi, mode is properly configured in my application, that is not a problem and I cannot even change it. Please suggest any alternative

Comment: Since you cannot modify configuration files and code, as well as models. You can try "timeout=-1". This means that it will never time out.

Comment: I tried but it says only positive integer values are allowed. Also, I want the timeout to not happen only when the user is active on the application, if it's idle I want the timeout as usual after 20 minutes

Comment: For **<SessionState>** this element, it has the following attributes: [sessionState Element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/h6bb9cz9(v%3dvs.100)). Based on your idea and the model you use, you must connect a **customProvider** to achieve this functionality.

Comment: I have all the configuration in place. What do you mean by connect?

Comment: Timeout means that if any commit is executed without operation, the tImeout time will count down from 20 minutes. When the user is active on the application, as long as the request is sent, the session does not expire. So I don't understand why your app works. In fact, this problem may be related to the work of your application, not to the setting of the session.

Comment: "When the user is active on the application, as long as the request is sent, the session does not expire." The session expires in this case, this is the problem. It shouldn't expire

Comment: In fact I think this issue should be fixed in the code. Because according to how session works, it will recalculate timeout whenever you send a request. Your program is active, but it still times out. This indicates that no requests were sent in the active state of your program. This leads to session timeout.